# Does the places of input matter? (SUMIFS)

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I have a question about Excel & VBA’s function SUMIFS(). I have two codes, but I changed the input-places from one to another (Århus & Odense, but 2 and 3 could also be used):

I need to find the correct sum when these criterias are used. I have tried to google and tried to understand SUMIFS. I tried to simulataing another dataset, with the same amount of variables and changes the different input locations. However, when comparing the 4 difference input places I get the same result

Code 1)

```
SUM(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$2000;$B$2:$B$2000;{"Odense";"Århus"};_

$C$2:$C$2000;{2;3};$E$2:$E$2000;ABS(I16)))
```

Code 2)

```
SUM(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$2000;$B$2:$B$2000;{"Århus";"Odense"};_

$C$2:$C$2000;{2;3};$E$2:$E$2000;ABS(I16)))
```

Code 1 gives 152832 and Code 2 gives 135751. So I hope that anyone can explain to me why this happen. Or maybe that there is something wrong with the data that is being used.

Comment: when you edit the formula are you using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter or Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using two arrays in SUMIFS if both arrays are vertical or both horizontal then it will matter as it will only do two and compare one to one stepping through each array the same.

If you want to do OR on both arrays then one must be Vertical and the other Horizontal:

```
SUM(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$2000;$B$2:$B$2000;{"Århus";"Odense"};$C$2:$C$2000;TRANSPOSE({2;3});$E$2:$E$2000;ABS(I16)))
```

Also note that when not in lockstep the max on the OR type is two arrays.

Comment: It worked. However, you are writting that when it is not in lockstep the max with OR are two arrays. But what is lockstep and could I add one or two more arrays, such as year?

=SUM(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$2000;$B$2:$B$2000;_
{"Odense";"Århus"};$C$2:$C$2000;TRANSPOSE({2;3});_
$E$2:$E$2000;ABS(I16);$F$2:$F$2000;{"2018";"2019"}))

Comment: Lockstep means it does: `(D="Odense" and C=2 and F=2018) OR (D="OÅrhusdense" and C=3 and F=2019)` not  `(D="Odense or D="OÅrhusdense) And (C=2 or C = 3) And (F=2018 or F = 2019)`  which is why you will get a different sum when changing the order.